# kotlin-coroutine can not be launched

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, coroutine, polling

when my fragment go backgroud of system, it invoke onStop().and then when my fragment go front desk of system, it invoke onResume(). but mainViewModelScope does not lanuch a coroutine.

my fragment

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.d("aaaa", "resume========")
        viewModel.startFetchDeviceTimer()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Log.d("aaaa", "stop========")
        viewModel.cancelFetchDeviceTimer()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.d("aaaa", "destroy========")
    }
```

my viewModel

```
    private val mainViewModelScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob())

    fun startFetchDeviceTimer() {
        startTimerActual()
    }

    private fun startTimerActual() {
         // launchWithVM({
        mainViewModelScope.launch {
            while (isActive) {
                Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().name)
                // 网络请求异步任务在IO线程的协程中
                ioScope.launch {
                    Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().name)
                    val deviceResponse = homeRepository.getDeviceList()
                    val deviceVOList = deviceResponse.deviceList.map { deviceModel ->
                        mapModel2VO(deviceModel)
                    }
                    deviceVOListData.postValue(deviceVOList)
                }
                delay(FETCH_DEVICE_INTERVAL.toDuration(DurationUnit.SECONDS))
            }
        }
        // }, {})
    }

    fun cancelFetchDeviceTimer() {
        if (mainViewModelScope.isActive) {
            mainViewModelScope.cancel()
        }
    }
```

I want mainViewModelScope to lanuch a coroutine when my fragment go front desk of system. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
            viewModel.startFetchDeviceTimer()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code and it work fine. **mainViewModelScope** will run every time onresume called. In case you cancel mainViewModelScope in onStop(), you could remove it. Please check

```
viewModel.cancelFetchDeviceTimer()
```

If you need cancel coroutine when app in background, you can use this way:

```
var mainViewModelScope: Job? = null

fun startTimerActual() {
   mainViewModelScope = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
       //do your job
   }
}

fun cancelFetchDeviceTimer() {
    mainViewModelScope?.cancel()
}
```

Comment: yes, i have cancelled the manViewModelScope in viewModel.cancelFetchDeviceTimer(). i supplemented cancelFetchDeviceTimer() in above code block. but when i remove viewModel.cancelFetchDeviceTimer() in onStop(), the polling job will keep runnig while i want the polling to stop when my fragment go backgroud of system. How can i do that. Thank you for you answer

Comment: You could cancel the `Job` returned by `launch` rather than cancelling the scope.

Comment: i am sorry for taking so late to reply you. Job or coroutine can not be start again after it stopped. l have to launch a new coroutine to do my job. but i have found a solution to finish my requirement. You can see my answer above